# An app to show facebook photo gallery

Tags: android, facebook

I wonder is there a way for me to pull facebook photo album and display it in my app?

Is there some way to just link Android image gallery to pull photos from FB so when they FB album updates my app will dynamically get the latest photo updates?

thanks

Comment: This could be a good intro, if you haven't read it already, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/

Comment: See the link the in comment above and then check out the Graph API. Either way, this is a very general question and it's hard to get a straight answer before actually building something.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it's quite general but I needed to know if it's at all possible or not. Will have a look at the link - thank you both